# A "Call" reminder Pop up?

Tags: excel, vba, popup, userform

I'm wondering if there is a VBA code that I can use that if a date in column R is today's date, that a reminder box can pop up and say "you have calls to make" or something along those lines? There may be numerous dates that are the same, but only need a box to pop up when worksheet is opened to make employee look at their call back list.

What I have now:

For Each c In checkhere
                If c.Value = Date Then
                MsgBox "You have some call backs to make"
                Exit For
                End If
            Next c

```
Dim NewControl As CommandBarControl
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Insert Date").Delete
Set NewControl = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add
With NewControl
    .Caption = "Insert Date"
    .OnAction = "Module1.OpenCalendar"
    .BeginGroup = True
End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `Workbook_Open()` to check for todays date in Col R. You might want to give it a try and post the code that you tried so that we can help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into 'ThisWorkbook'

```
            Private Sub Workbook_Open()

            Dim checkhere As Range

            Set sh = Sheets("yoursheethere")
            Set checkhere = sh.Range("R1:R" & sh.Range("R1").End(xlDown).Row)

            For Each c In checkhere

                If c.Value = Date Then
                MsgBox "You have some unanswered calls"
                Exit For
                End If
            Next c

            End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Gr8 :) You might want to specify which sheet the range R is in else it will always take the `ActiveSheet` ;)

Comment: Ah.. I copied and pasted, but I think I deleted some of my other code.. now I"m totally lost!! Yikes..

Comment: Paste it a couple of lines below the text that is already there

Comment: This works great for one sheet in the workbook. But each month is a different sheet. How can I alter the code to open for each sheet?